# Having issues with my ionic login app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am trying to create a login application with create account option.When i run the ionic serve i get a white screen.
Heres code i have done so far
(am totally new to this stuff )

index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  </body>
```

login.html

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-content>

  <div class="login-image">
     <img src="../img/img3.jpg" width="100%" class="padding">
   </div>

   <div class="padding">  
    <form ng-submit="doLogin()" >
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label"></span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username" placeholder="Username">
          </label><br>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label"></span>
            <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password" placeholder="Password">
          </label><br>
           <div style=" text-align: right;">
             <a href="#/"> Forgot Password </a>
           </div><br>
          <label>
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" href = "template/dashboard.html">Log in</button>
          </label>
          <br>
           <div style=" text-align: center;">
             <a href="template/createaccount.html">Create Account</a>
           </div>
        </div>
      </form>
   </div>

 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

createaccount.html

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div>
      <form name="createaccountform" class="padding">
        <div>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
            <label>
             <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" href="template/login.html">Create Account </button> 
           </label>         
        </div>      
      </form>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider

    .state('index',{
      url: '/index',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: '/index.html'

       })

    .state('login',{
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
    }) 

    .state('createaccount',{
      url: '/createaccount',
      templateUrl: 'templates/createaccount.html'
    });




    //allows for fallback when page not found or not exist
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('templates/login.html');

});
```

Dont know what am dong wrong but i really need a guide on this.

Comment: change the otherwise route to .otherwise('/login')

Answer (score 0):

After of run your command, need to access to the following URL to see your login page:

```
http://localhost:8000/login
```

The routing is handled in your `app.js` file throughout state manager.
I suggest taking at look at the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) to understand how works.

Comment: Thank you 
But when i click on the create account it gives an error ie.
GET http://localhost:8100/template/createaccount.html 404 (not found)

Comment: Please post your answer

Comment: after changing the otherwise route to ('/login') it solved all my issues.
That of the createaccount.html 404 error was because of a typo in my app.js(template instead of templates)